# Is it acceptable to ask a manager for a company I'm applying to about her previous work experience?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry

For information I'm a web developer and live in France.

I will soon have an phone interview with a manager from company A so that we can discuss any mission they might have for me, if my profile would fit within the company and so on.

I was given the first name of the manager that would interview me and I looked her up on Linkedin with her first name and the name of the company and found her, supposedly. While the person I found could be someone else in the company A and not my interviewer, if it were to be the correct person I found that she worked for company B for quite some time and I'm also in contact with company B.

Would it be acceptable to ask her why she left company B ? Or would it be inappropriate since I'm the interviewee ?

Comment: If you're unsure that you have found the correct person, it might be best to wait and see if she brings up the common ground first.

Comment: @Kozaky Of course, my plan was to wait for her to introduce herself and see if the last name would match then if the interview goes well, ask the question at the very end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some better ways to phrase it would be "What reasons drove you to join Company A ?" ; or "How is Company A different than other companies ?"

You have a strong chance that the interviewer will answer with some of the reasons why she left company B. Depending on how friendly the conversation is, you might have the opportunity to gather information at that point.

If she doesn't talk about company B on her own, I'd suggest not mentioning it. **The subject of your interview is yourself and company A, nothing else.**

Answer (score 1):

It would only be appropriate to mention company b if you re given an opening to do so, ie in response to a question about previous employers, most likely in the personal interview and not the phone one, and only in the context that you ve done your research on company A and your recruiter. Asking the recruiter why they left company B would be inappropriate at all times, at least as I see it.